# mongodb scopeddbconnection with c++

Tags: c++, mongodb, connection, pool

I'm positive I'm getting al this wrong, but here's my question:

I need a connection pool to mongo which I create like so:

```
mongo::ScopedDbConnection connectionPool("localhost");
```

Then on each thread, I do:

```
mongo::DBClientConnection c(connectionPool.get());   <-- is this even right?
```

Next I need to run

```
c.runCommand()
```

and give the connection back:

```
connectionPool.done();
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: did you get it to work? if not did you try asking here? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user

Answer (score 1):

I got it works like this:

```
mongo::ScopedDbConnection* c;
c = mongo::ScopedDbConnection::getScopedDbConnection("127.0.0.1");
if( c->ok() )
{
  c->get()->runCommand( "tracer", query_upsert_document, objError );
  c->done();
}
```

Thanks all for your help!

Regards,